# Will I be able to `import <standard_headers>`?

Tags: c++, module, c++20

Multiple talks have taught me that we can `import <standardheaders>`, but this does not seem to work at all in Compiler Explorer. In latest Clang and GCC, I just get errors, and when googling for this, I see some Microsoft documents that say it's doable, but they seem very non-standard in their approach, regrouping the headers in some vendor-specific way.

What gives?

Will we be able to do this? or it is never gonna happen in a standard way? Is it dependent on a build system doing it for us individually even though they are standard headers? Was this a planned feature that was dropped? Or was it always planned to be highly vendor specific and non-standardized, and to require a build system even for standard headers? Is there a plan to standardize at least the division of standard features so that we don't have a bunch of different vendor specific organization schemes that are different than the header scheme?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support . modules are already in C++20. No compiler fully implements them yet. Modularization of the standard library might come in a future standard.

Comment: Which talks?  Which version of C++ are you using?  Which version of C++ do you think supports that feature?  Which version of C++ does your compiler (or compiler options) support?

Comment: "*I just get errors*" What kind of errors?

Comment: About lacking header units.

Answer (score 4):

The proposal to make standard headers importable as synthesized header units is [P1502](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1502r1.html).

STL says in MSVC's [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/60#issuecomment-784748794) that it is feature complete for VS 2019 16.10 Preview 2.

Neither GCC [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11) nor Clang [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx20) list their current status for P1502, but support for modules in general is "partial".

> Will we be able to do this?

Presumably when the compiler / standard library implementers get to it. Until then, we can safely use `#include` which doesn't have drawbacks compared to synthesized header units.

Comment: Thank you! I was confused because I thought this was already doable and was very surprised by the errors I got about them not being header units. This made me wonder whether we have to manually make our own header units or needed a separate build system for standard header units. Reading P1502 shows that it should in fact eventually work the way I expected, if I'm reading it right. "We propose to guarantee that the C++ standard library headers can be imported as header units..."